# PTR records are not valid. but they should be!! - PTR quandary

Tags: linux, email, ptr-record

I have a perplexing problem from my point of view. Not a mail server expert though so here goes;

Using mail-tester.com, done a spam test for my mailserver and it's telling my PTR record is invalid, but i believe it should be valid, it's currently in this format;

```
HELO: domain.org
rDNS: server1.domain.org
```

This should be valid, i have been told it should pretty much be either `server1`. or `mail1`. etc.

the HELO and rDNS can be the same FQDN though? `example.org`

But I have been told setting both the hostname and rDNS identically the same can cause conflicts.

Not sure which format it should be in?

```
HELO: example.org
rDNS: server1.example.org
```

or

```
HELO: example.org
rDNS: example.org
```

Comment: Note that neither the HELO/EHLO response nor the PTR (or other DNS records) are necessarily related to the server's internal hostname. The HELO hostname can be set in most mail server configurations (the configuration file for the MTA itself, e.g. /etc/postfix/main.conf) and the PTR record is external.

Answer (score 3):

Neither.

Both your server's hostname and PTR record should be a fully qualified domain name, e.g. `server1.example.org`.

Comment: thanks for the quick response!

is it easy to change the hostname once i've set everything up already?

Comment: It's generally trivial to change your server's hostname, but you do need to restart affected services (or just the whole computer).